# Embedding terminal in a node-webkit app?

Tags: node.js, terminal, node-webkit

I am using node-webkit to build a text editor . However, I want the terminal to be embedded in the application. Kind off like SublimeREPL . 
I haven't found a way this can be achieved. Need some guidance here .Is there a web plugin or something that can help ?
Also the part that confuses me is, how does this embedded terminal communicates with the system terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help you https://github.com/Gottox/node-webterm (also on [dailyjs.com](http://dailyjs.com/2015/01/22/terminaljs/))

Only ui: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/

if you will need to make backend by yourself, it's relatively simple: run child process and stream stdout to print, and user input to stdin.

Answer (score 0):

You need a virtual server on the backend to handle your requests on the frontend. Search if Terminal.com or koding.io offer APIs.